# Use view as base container Android

Tags: java, android

Here is the scope. I am trying to create a base class you will be subclassing and running into some snags. I want to create a method that returns a view so it can be overridden by any of its subclasses such as `ListView`, `GridView`, `TextView`, etc. Not sure if that is even possible or if I am going about it the wrong way, but here is the code below.

This is the base view method in my class:

```
    View backViewController()
{
    return null;
}
```

Here is the subclass:

```
@Override
    View backViewController()
{
    MenuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.backView);
    return MenuList;
}
```

With MenuList being a ListView I created in the subclass and trying to use in place of the base View. The error I am receiving is "The return type is incompatible".

Comment: I'm not sure how this code is even compiling. Is `MenuList` a class or a variable? Can you please post more of the code?

Comment: respect java naming conventions, your code is hard to read. http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Comment: MenuList is a private ListView, but I am getting a cast class exception, just not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is R.id.backView a ListView in the xml layout ?

Comment: no it is just a View. I was hoping to be able to have just a view so I could use it's subclasses, but it is beginning to look like that might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works, as menuList would by a view by inheritence. So the error must be somewhere else, check your type hierarchy in eclipse, or check that you imported the right classes.

Comment: thanks, I am getting a cast class exception, so not sure why that would give a class cast exception when the code should work. Is it a problem with the resource XML file? If needed, I can post both XML and the full java class

Comment: Show your imports (and please take some time to read and respect java naming conventions, use eclipse's refactoring -rename- from menu)